# Strange Behavior in Append

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have a list that I need to extract, via 'filter', certain matching values. The problem is that the 'append' method seems to create an array while appending the matching values. How do I change this behavior?

My code:

```
    v_Files = ['aaa.mp3', 'hhh.mp4', 'jjj.txt', 'uuu.xls', 'ujh.mp3', 'hun.m4p']
print("Files list: %s") %(v_Files)
v_NewFiles = (filter(lambda element: 'mp3' in element, v_Files))
v_NewFiles.append(filter(lambda element: 'mp4' in element, v_Files))
v_NewFiles.append(filter(lambda element: 'm4p' in element, v_Files))
print("New files list: %s") %(v_NewFiles)
```

And the output:

```
Files list: ['aaa.mp3', 'hhh.mp4', 'jjj.txt', 'uuu.xls', 'ujh.mp3', 'hun.m4p']
New files list: ['aaa.mp3', 'ujh.mp3', ['hhh.mp4'], ['hun.m4p']]
```

As can be seen, the new list from the 'append' method has become a mess.

Feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: At least care to tag the language you are coding in.

Comment: I have just about abandoned tags, as just about all tags seem to require 1,500 rep. I will make sure to include Python in the future though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Seems in my push to move beyond beginner I forgot some basic things. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend?rq=1). Seems I forgot about 'extend'.

Using 'extend' instead of 'append' solved my problem.